# How could I organize this code?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, readability, maintainability

myThread is a function that is executed every second, basicly it reads some data that has to be parsed and executed. The function grew a lot and it is over 1500 lines of code like the sample below with lots of [if else if else] blocks lots of repetitions like sleep or SendToChat to send a command to the console, and its being a lot difficult to maintain, make changes, etc, to it.

I would like some advices (if possible with code examples, that would help me understand the layout) on how I could rewrite this, I am not very experienced so I am not so sure of the possibilities to turn this code into a better code for maintainability and readability ?

Also feel free to comment on any functions or anything else as it could help me improve on other things that are wrong.

**This is just some sample of the code and not the entire code if you feel like you need any other information from the code feel free to ask and I will post once I can.**

PS: this is not an irc thing.

```
private void myThread()
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        // SOME PARSED DATA HERE
        // if (parsedData matchs) do the below stuff
        Messages received = new Messages
        {
            Sent = Convert.ToDateTime(match.Groups[1].Value),
            Username = match.Groups[3].Value,
            MessageType = (match.Groups[2].Length > 0) ? MsgType.System : MsgType.Chat,
            Message = match.Groups[4].Value.Trim(),
            CommandArgs = match.Groups[4].Value.ToLower().Trim().Split(' ')
        };

        // Get the user that issued the command
        User user = usersList.Find(x => x.Name == recebe.received.ToLower());
        if (user != null)
        {
            // different greetings based on acess level
            if (received.Message == "has entered this room")
            {
                if (User == null)
                {
                    SendToChat("/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + " you have no registration.");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    SendToChat("/kick " + received.Username + " not registered.");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    string cmd = (user.Access < Access.Vouch) ?
                        "/ann " + user.Access.ToString() + " <" + received.Username + "> has entered the room." :
                        "/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + " welcome to our room !";
                    SendToChat(cmd);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            // Here we filter all messages that start with a . which means it is a command
            else if (received.Message.StartsWith(".") && user != null)
            {
                // here we verify if the user has Access to use the typed command and/or if the command exists 
                if (accessList.Exists(x => x.Access == user.Access && x.HasCommand(received.CommandArgs[0])))
                {
                    if (received.CommandArgs[0] == ".say")
                    {
                        SendToChat("/ann " + received.Username + " says: " + received.Message.Substring(received.CommandArgs[0].Length + 1));
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    else if (received.CommandArgs[0] == ".command")
                    {
                        string allowedList = string.Empty;
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (string cmd in listaAccesss.Find(x => x.Access == user.Access).Command)
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                                allowedList += cmd;
                            else
                                allowedList +=  ", " + cmd;
                        }
                        SendToChat("/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + " you are allowed to use the followed commands: " + permite);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                    }
                    else if (received.CommandArgs[0] == ".vip")
                    {
                        if (received.Command.Count() < 2)
                        {
                            SendToChat("/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + ", see an example of how to use this command: .vip jonh");
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }
                        else if (received.Command.Count() == 2)
                        {
                            var target = usersList.Find(x => x.Name == received.CommandArgs[1]);
                            if (target == null)
                            {
                                User newUser = new User
                                {
                                    Name = received.CommandArgs[1].ToLower(),
                                    Access = Access.VIP,
                                    Registered = DateTime.Now,
                                    RegisteredBy = received.Username.ToLower()
                                };

                                usersList.Add(newUser);

                                SendToChat("/ann " + user.Access.ToString() + " " + user.Name + " has promoted " + received.CommandArgs[1] + " to VIP.");
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                            else if (target != null && target.Access == Access.VIP)
                            {
                                SendToChat("/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + " the user " + target.Name + " already have VIP access.");
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                            else if (target != null && user.Access == Access.HeadAdmin && user.Access < target.Access)
                            {
                                Access last = target.Access;
                                target.Access = Access.Vouch;

                                SendToChat("/ann " + user.Access.ToString() + " " + received.Username + " promoted/demoted the " + last.ToString() + " " + target.Name + " to VIP.");
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                            else if (target != null && target.Access == Access.Vouch)
                            {
                                target.Access = Access.VIP;
                                target.RegisteredBy = user.Name;

                                SendToChat("/ann " + user.Access.ToString() + " " + received.Username + " promoted the vouch of " + target.Name + " to VIP.");
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SendToChat("/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + " you can't register or modify the user " + received.CommandArgs[1] + ".");
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SendToChat("/w " + received.Username + " " + received.Username + " command not found.");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @carlosfigueira I think my question does fit in here as well as I am not only looking for advices, suggestions but I am also looking for potential coding examples that a community member could be interested in showing to help me in my learning and I am sure many users have gone thru this experience once, but i will keep codereview in mind I was not aware of it..

Comment: This question is basically off-topic according to the FAQ.  It is not "a specific programming problem", and "every answer is equally valid".  There is also a much more on-topic stackexchange site, as carlosfigueira mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to organize this code is by using the "[Chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)" design pattern.

The idea is to have one class for each "command" that knows what to do, for example:

```
public class NewUserCommand : ConsoleCommand
{
    public override void Process(Context context, string command)
    {
        if (context.User != null)
        {
            // different greetings based on acess level
            if (context.Received.Message == "has entered this room")
            {
                if (context.User == null)
                {
                    SendToChat("/w " + context.Received.Username + " " + context.Received.Username + " you have no registration.");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    SendToChat("/kick " + context.Received.Username + " not registered.");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    //I could process the request
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        //I dont know what to do, continue with the next processor
        this.Successor.Process(context, command);
    }
}
```

You will need one of these classes for every command.

Comment: +1 that is interesting I was considering doing something similar for the commands since I know all variable each command has but was not sure on how to go with it, there are several interesting replies here and i am going 1 by 1 before start it over.

Answer (score 7):

Often when you see complicated conditional logic (lots of if/else blocks and nested conditions), you should consider refactoring your code into the [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) or [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design patterns (depends on the situation). Have a look at those for some ideas.

UPDATE:
If you're having trouble on how to refactor your code, there is a great book I read recently that helps break the process down (covers everything from adding version control, to unit testing, to continuous integration... also talks about breaking things down iteratively until you are able to apply things like dependency injection etc.). It doesn't cover any of the topics in complete depth, because there are entire books dedicated to each individual subject, but it's a great starting point:
[Brownfield Application Development in .Net](http://www.manning.com/baley/)

Comment: +1 thanks that does help a lot specially with the examples for some reason I have more facility to learn when looking at some code together with materials etc.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make a little trick that, while is not a good method of refactoring, makes the code more readable.

Instead of having:

```
if (condition1) {
    statement1;
} else if (condition2) {
    statement2;
    if (condition3) {
       statement3;
    }
}
```

... I use:

```
if (condition1) {
    statement1;
    return;
}

if (condition2) {
    statement;
    return;
}
if (condition2 && condition3) {
    statement3;
    return;
}
```

Reducing the complexity of the code is the first step to break it apart. Next steps in order for me to take are:

- refactoring into different methods
- finding similar methods, refactoring and having helper methods
- moving methods that do not depend of internal data to other classes
- when you seem to have two different methods that deal with complete different "things", make them separate classes (that's a major effort, specially on lengthy codes)
- when you get things separated but procedural, you may start applying patterns that would make your code less repeated. Jason Down mentioned State, Strategy, but Factory, Template Method and most of them would also do, depending on your needs.

Comment: thanks those are good advices specially as I was kinda lost of how to get started to define where to put what etc... separating all the conditions would help me see thru in a easier manner

Answer (score 1):

It definitely needs some refactoring. A few things:

- [Don't repeate yourself](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) (f.e. Thread.Sleep(1000);
  )
- Split it into a few methods
- Seperate your logic from costruction.
- Use [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)  (Messages, isRunning should be passed to method).
- Rather than using multiple flags use Polymorphism - [nice talkon this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)

Comment: +1 indeed initially the code was something very small was I saw no problem having it like it was but then it start growing too fast with lots of commands and I am tired of all the confusing blocks the dependency injection seems exactly what I need I am still having some difficult to put it in practice thought

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the beginning, i think you should split this huge code into several methods. To separate this logical parts that you have commented. You should have one method for each part of comment (that's minimum). Try for beginning this:

1. Method: // SOME PARSED DATA HERE
          // if (parsedData matchs) do the below stuff
   Try to make one method of this.
2. Method   // Get the user that issued the command
3. Method   // different greetings based on acess level
4. Method // Here we filter all messages that start with a . which means it is a command

and so on...

And you MUST make methods of parts that repeat so you can make changes always on just one place, not to search throught all code and change every parameter to new value.